# Unity Prefabs won't load when using built app

Tags: unity-game-engine

Problems occurs only when I build my application. According to the logs all the Prefabs aren't load at all. What to do ?

Comment: Could you please provide some sample logs?

Comment: Where are your prefabs stored? How do you reference them in code?

Comment: They are in `Assets/Resources/Prefabs` and access them via the classical `Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/...");`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the right scene is checked inside "Build Settings" window.

If you have multiple scenes, set index for initial scene to 0.

Look at "**Scenes In Build**" here:

[image]

Comment: Play with a blank scene. Something is really wrong with scene. Maybe do "Save as..." for your scene and build the copy. One time this helped me (sounds crazy however).